# Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() - output is empty. Running the same app from cmd - output is OK

Tags: c#, ironpython, iar

I'm trying to get output while building a project with `IarBuild.exe` utility (`IAR` cmd utility to build a project)
I'm using a simple `IronPython` script:

```
    process = System.Diagnostics.Process()
    process.StartInfo.FileName = path_process
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = command_line_arguments
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    process.Start()
    output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    process.WaitForExit()

    return {"Exit code": process.ExitCode, "Output": output}
```

In my case "Output" always empty ("StandardError" is also empty).
If I try to execute the same app in command line ("cmd.exe") the output is successfully displayed.

Maybe the issue is related to some OS setting (or changes that were made by other installed application) because when I try to execute the same script on other virtual machine (same OS) the `Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` is OK.

I have the same result when I use "subprocess.call()" method instead of "System.Diagnostics.Process()"

Comment: what's the command line argument and path process.

Comment: path_process = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.2\common\bin\IarBuild.exe"; command_line_arguments = "C:\\test\\test.ewp -build Debug -log info"

Answer (score 0):

when you are passing arguments.It appears you are passing three arguments:

1) C:\test\test.ewp
2) -build Debug
3) -log info 
but they are being considered as 6 arguments as they contain spaces.

use

```
command_line_arguments = "\"C:\\test\\test.ewp\" \"-build Debug\" \"-log info\""
```

I might be wrong. For further reference, have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Three arguments are parsed correctly by IAR only output is not displayed

Comment: Then I guess you would need to specify your working directory as well. Process.startinfo.WorkingDirectory= @"".. as per your requirement.
Quite possible it's creating the output but in some other location.